# Tkinter Window is freezing when User input submitted

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I open a tkinter window for user's to put player names into which will become the save file name containing points players have scored in the game, the tkinter window opens and as soon as the submit button is clicked the game essentially freeze's and I have to close the game. How do I stop it from freezing? Here is the code:

```
print(str(redpoints))
print(str(yellowpoints))

master = Tk()
master.title('Save File Name')
v = StringVar()


# Variable to hold the input
inp = None

L1 = Label(master, text = 'Enter Player Names:')
L1.pack(side = LEFT)

E1 = Entry(master, textvariable = v, bd = 5)
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)

def userinput():
    # Declare 'inp' to be global
    global inp
    savename = input(v.get())
    print (savename)
    # Update the variable
    inp = savename


Submit = Button(master, text = 'Submit', command = userinput)
Submit.pack(side = BOTTOM)
print(inp)
master.mainloop()
answer = (str(redpoints), " ", str(yellowpoints))
example = open(inp + '.txt', 'w') #opening the file, 'w' allows to write in it.
example.write(answer)
example.close()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

It crashes before the user input = savename

Comment: You say that pygame is crashing, but the code here doesn't involve pygame at all. How is this possible?

Comment: I shoud edit the title, but I have made connect 4 and its using pygame but I have a button in pygame called 'save' which runs a function I've defined as save opening the tkinter window which is coded above. When save is clicked  and I click submit everything freeze's. Both the pygame window and the now opened tkinter window

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do. What is `input()` supposed to achieve in this code?

Comment: The user is to input a line which will end up being the name of the save file, which saves the current scores of the players. Where I've written inp + '.txt' is combining the user inputted name with txt to make it a file

Comment: But `savename` is supposed to be set by the `Entry`-Object you created (`E1`). `input()` targets console inputs. Just get rid of it and directly use `v.get()` as this is the variable holding the player names

Comment: All you are doing is prompting the user with the text they typed in the entry widget for them to type something. `input` detracts from the GUI causing it to stall until you respond to the `input` command in the shell.

Comment: So I placed v.get() instead of inp + 'txt' and It didnt freeze anymore, although it never asked me to submit an input which means the file was created without a name

Comment: So how do I get the input they type in the tkinter window, once they click submit to become the file name?

Comment: `v.get()` is what they type in the entry box